# Image on top of frame (center position) absolute layout or any other solution xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have to admit absolutelayout is the  thing that does not get into my head.
Can you help?

I need to put an image on top of a frame -grid etc.. on few screen so I must find a solution that works.

This is what I want to achieve

[image]

This is what I have done used boxview (purple) supposed to be my img1.

MyXaml

```
  <AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <BoxView Color="Purple" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" 
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"></BoxView>
        <Frame
        Padding="0"
        BorderColor="Green"
        CornerRadius="10">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Color="Red"/>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5" Color="GreenYellow"/>
                </Grid>

                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Coral" Margin="20,0,20,0"
                TextColor="White" Text="Label 3" />
                <!--other stuff down here -->
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

My Result (as you can see I get a long rectangle when all i want is the boxview in the middle like above). Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Move the box outside the StackLayout and move it as the last item in the hierarchy

Comment: @Cheesebaron hi thanks for your reply.I have tried it but does not work.obviously I am doing something wrong.Could you post it what you mean?many thanks

Comment: all your content is in a StackLayout, which means that it will be laid out in the order specified.  The AbsoluteLayout is pointless if you do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started (I mod'ed a demo of mine, so adjust accordingly):

[image]

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,.50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="#66000000" Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <Frame CornerRadius="10" Margin="20,20,20,20" BackgroundColor="Black" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1">
        <Grid Margin="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Left" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Label Text="Right" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Label Text="Across Page" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
    <Image Source="yt.png" 
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0,50,50" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: wow. huge thanks! i really need to find some good sample led tutorial about absolute layout.The MS docs not great to me.. I will struggle again unless I understant it. again thank you

Comment: hi wondering if you could advice on something. Tried to get in a bigger image but i couldnt.I tried different solutions but I cannot seem to make the image bigger.Which bits do i have to change so that I can adjust the image size? Many thanks for your help

Comment: @developer9969 In this case, the `50,50` in `".5,0,50,50"` are the width/height of the view https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#specifying-values